# Customize WM_NAME and WM_CLASS (as shown by xprop) in PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt4

How can I customize the strings `WM_NAME` and `WM_CLASS` of a `PyQt4` program as shown by `xprop`?

Consider for example:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("plastique")


    listView = QtGui.QListView()    
    listView.show()

    combobox = QtGui.QComboBox()
    combobox.show()    

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If I run this (the file is called `xprop_test.py`) via `python xprop_test.py` and invoke the linux tool `xprop` either for the ListView Or for the ComboBox, it shows

```
WM_NAME(STRING) = "xprop_test.py"
```

and

```
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "xprop_test.py", "Xprop_test.py"
```

How can I set the strings `WM_NAME` and `WM_CLASS` to another custom value (different from the filename)?

How can I set it for the whole program? How can I adjust it for each individual GUI element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `WM_NAME` string is simply the title-bar caption, which can be set like this:

```
listView.setWindowTitle('listview')
```

giving:

```
WM_NAME(STRING) = "listView"
```

The `WM_CLASS` is harder to affect. By default, it's constructed from `argv[0]`, and there does not appear to be a way to change this programmatically using the Qt APIs. However, the first part of the string can be changed by running the program with a `-name` option like this:

```
python xprop_test.py -name FooBar
```

giving:

```
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "FooBar", "Xprop_test.py"
```